# Trying to query all the columns and their names from a staged file Snowflake

Tags: sql, file, compilation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, querying

I am using this query to get one of the files that I have staged. I do not know how many columns the file contains and would like to query all of the columns as well as be able to see the names of the columns.

I am doing

```
SELECT a.$1, a.$2, a.$3, a.$4
FROM @my_stage (FILE_FORMAT=>'my_format',PATTERN=>'my_file_path') a;
```

which gives the columns with names $1, $2 etc and their values. Since I do not know how many columns exist in this raw file, I will have to keep adding a.$5, a.$6 and so on to the select statement until no more columns show up. Is there a way I can just query all of the columns at once as well as what the column names are? I tried using `SELECT *`but got an error saying `SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 0 SELECT with no columns` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simply "select *" and return all the columns from a given file on a stage.

Assuming your data is in CSV format and without headers, you cannot even return the "column names" as there are no names available.

If however your first line in the file includes a name for each column (eg. extracted from excel where the first line includes the names of each column), then you could simply query these using:

```
SELECT a.$1, a.$2, a.$3, a.$4
FROM @my_stage (FILE_FORMAT=>'my_format',PATTERN=>'my_file_path') a;
```

The first line in the file indicates the column names.

One way to get the column details without knowing the column names:

Create an external table over the file.  This will return the data in VARIANT format - and you could simply query the external table.  If course this will only work on CSV data if your first line includes column headers.

Comment: How can I create an external table? I was able to change the file format so that the first line of the csv would have the column headers

Comment: I was able to do 
```create or replace external table et1
 location=@my_stage/file_path
 file_format = my_format; 

alter external table et1 refresh;``` 
but when I do ```select * from et1``` nothing is returned

Comment: The above approach includes the column headers as data points in the query results/ How to skip file header while reading?